# Scrapping de HTML com Javascript puro

Tags: javascript, aplicação-web, scraping

Olá, tenho um html que tem a seguinte sequencia de exemplo:

`<links class="canais-teste"> CANAL 1 <links/>`

Existem uns 80 trechos desses, queria pegar só os conteudos de dentro dessas tags, no caso o "CANAL1", como posso fazer isso com javascript puro?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('links');
for (let i = 0 ; i < links.length ; i++){
  console.log(links[i].innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<links class="canais-teste"> CANAL 1 </links>
<links class="canais-teste"> CANAL 2 </links>
<links class="canais-teste"> CANAL 3 </links>
```

Comment: Lucas, no caso no HTML existem várias tags links, porém com classes diferentes, como pego os dados da tag links dessa especifica classe e que esteja dentro de uma tag span?


<span class="display-name ">
          <span>
            Zero Bugs
          </span>
        </span>